# how to highlight searched text with different color in Text in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am creating a demo for RichText where I have a text and a text field,

Text widget showing a string 'Welcome to flutter' and I have a text field for input of searching word inside that string. and a button to show the search result

I have almost done with Exact word searching, But now I want to implement
it should be also highlighted when the word is half entered like, 'Flut', and these 4 characters should be shown with different colors.
[image]

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    String mystring = 'Welcome to Flutter';
    mywords = mystring.split(' ');
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 30.0, horizontal: 10),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              SizedBox(
                height: 20,
              ),
              TextField(
                controller: txtsearch,
              ),
              ElevatedButton(onPressed: (){setState(() {

              });}, child: Text('Search Word in String')),
              SizedBox(
                height: 20,
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 20,
              ),
              RichText(
                  text: TextSpan(
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.black),
                children: mywords.map((e) {
                  if(e!=txtsearch.text)
                  return TextSpan(text: e+' ');
                  //and suggest me is there any other way to add space instread of the way i used
                  else
                    return TextSpan(text: e+' ',style: TextStyle(

                        color: Colors.blue));
                }).toList(),
              ))
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it important that each match is restricted to a single word, or do you actually want each substring within the entire string? If the second, you can use `String.allMatches` to find the start and end indices of the matches and then construct a list of `TextSpan` widgets from that. Something like this:

```dart
    final search = txtsearch.text.toLowerCase();
    final text = widget.text;
    final matches = search.allMatches(text.toLowerCase()).toList();
    final spans = <TextSpan>[];

    if (matches.isEmpty) {
      spans.add(TextSpan(text: text));
    } else {
      for (var i = 0; i < matches.length; i++) {
        final strStart = i == 0 ? 0 : matches[i - 1].end;
        final match = matches[i];
        spans.add(
          TextSpan(
            text: text.substring(
              strStart,
              match.start,
            ),
          ),
        );
        spans.add(
          TextSpan(
            text: text.substring(
              match.start,
              match.end,
            ),
            style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.blue),
          ),
        );
      }
      spans.add(TextSpan(text: text.substring(matches.last.end)));
    }
```

It's probably possible to make the loop logic a bit prettier. [Working dartpad here](https://dartpad.dev/?id=d89aff99240c19c3a865af453faecf41).

Comment: Actually this is not what exactly I want but your logic will help me to complete it..Thanks....and pls upvote if question is like that kind....